# django commit 2 transactions at the same time

Tags: django, transactions

I have a model with a unique position (a queue). now when I want to move an object up or down in the queue I have to change the 2 swap position in queue.
However when I try to save them (I guess this is because everything gets committed automatically) the unique constraint gets violated.

How can save both changes in one transaction?

example:

```
skill_1 = Skill.object.get(position=3)
skill_2 = Skill.object.get(position=4)
skill_1.position = 4
skill_2.position = 3
skill_1.save()
skill_2.save()
```

Comment: What is the problem? You want modify 2 objects in 1 query?

Comment: yes.  on the first save, the skill.position is not unique cause the other skill has not yet been updated in the database yet. (and visa versa)  so somehow i need to save them on the same action

Comment: I have just give ans answer about [pre_save](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31441393/3945375) method, you could also check [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) in docs.

Comment: You're looking for deferred constraint checking. I don't believe Django provides an API for this. You'll have to check the documentation of your database backend for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to control transactions explicitly using [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/)

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):

    with transaction.atomic():
        skill_1 = Skill.object.get(position=3)
        skill_2 = Skill.object.get(position=4)
        skill_1.position = 4
        skill_2.position = 3
        skill_1.save()
        skill_2.save()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this insight. I didn't realize i could use atmoic for this. I can test on this moment however and will marks as right answer when I have tested it this evening

Comment: This is the right answer. no need to do tricky shit with pre_save or raw SQL